# Long equation in latex

Tags: equations

I am trying to write the following equation but `overfull \hbox` will appear after running LaTeX to get a pdf. Could you please help me to write it in a proper way. Many thanks.

```
$$
(v_{-n}\dots v_{-1} \otimes v_{0} \otimes v_{1}\dots v_{m}) \dashv
(w_{-p}\dots w_{-1} \otimes w_{0} \otimes w_{1} \dots w_{q})\\
&=v_{-n}\dotsv_{-1} \otimes v_{0} \otimes v_{1} \dots v_{m}w_{-p}\dots
w_{q}
$$.
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: See [Why is `\[` ... `\]` preferable to `$$` ... `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you use the `amsmath` package and `\[` … `\]` instead of `$$`, [as described here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to), or choose any other `amsmath` environments.  I chose `multline*` for an environment since your `&` alignment was aligning to nothing.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
(v_{-n}\dots v_{-1} \otimes v_{0} \otimes v_{1}\dots v_{m}) \mathbin\dashv (w_{-p}\dots w_{-1} \otimes w_{0} \otimes w_{1} \dots w_{q})\\
    =v_{-n}\dots v_{-1} \otimes v_{0} \otimes v_{1} \dots v_{m}w_{-p}\dots w_{q}
    \end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please mind that you had many typos in the code. Also, as @egreg points out, `\dashv` needs to be prefixed with `\mathbin` to yield a binary operator, with proper spacing

Comment: `\dashv` is defined in the kernel, but it's a relation symbol and it seems to be used here as a binary operation, so `\mathbin\dashv`

Comment: @egreg roger, I just thought it was a typo, only later realised it was real :) correcting it